# Free RichTextEditor for ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, rich-text-editor

I want to use a Rich Text Editor in my ASP.NET web application project for my company's product. What are the best free options available? I reviewed [the ASP.NET Ajax HTML Editor](http://www.asp.net/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx). But it does not support inserting an image inside the content. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

I had a look at tinymce,FCKeditor etc... But i am afraid to take it as there is some licensing is present for those.

Answer (score 3):

[TinyMCE - Javascript WYSIWYG Editor](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Hai shyju,

- Jquery Text Editor ([10 jQuery and non-jQuery javascript Rich Text Editors](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors))
- [AjaxControlToolkit TextEditor](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx)
- [Yui Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/switch_editor.html)
- [StackOverflow's own Text Editor(**WMD: The Wysiwym Markdown Editor**)](http://wmd-editor.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the editors free or commercial will have some kind of license if its being supported. I looked at various editors when looking at integrating one into our cms and cameto the following conclusion: I thought FCKEditor was the best "free" editor at the time on but eventually used the CuteSoft Editor from http://www.cutesoft.net/ASP.NET+WYSIWYG+Editor/
I can highly recommend it and since you are using for a commercial product, it worth having a royalty free license and technical support.

I would also look at the new jquery based editors.